# Как получать почту php скриптом?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Есть скрипт который получает письма на php.Как Только сейчас он получает название папок которые созданы на почтовике. Как можно его модифицировать, чтоб получать не только названия папок а ещё и тему письма, адресатов, и само тело письма ?

Вот пример скрипта:

```js
$mbox = imap_open("{imap.mail.ru.mail.ru:143}", "wwwwwwww", "wwwwww");

echo "<h1>Mailboxes</h1>\n";
$folders = imap_listmailbox($mbox, "{imap.mail.ru.mail.ru:143}", "*");

if ($folders == false) {
    echo "Call failed<br />\n";
} else {
    foreach ($folders as $val) {
        echo $val . "<br />\n";
    }
}

echo "<h1>Headers in INBOX</h1>\n";
$headers = imap_headers($mbox);

if ($headers == false) {
    echo "Call failed<br />\n";
} else {
    foreach ($headers as $val) {
        echo $val . "<br />\n";
    }
}

imap_close($mbox);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть готовая библиотека для работы с imap.

https://github.com/gotha/PHP-IMAP-library/blob/master/MailLib.php

Реализации функционала можешь посмотреть у него, либо саму библиотеку и использовать